# iOS - When global calculation happens UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
class HealthViewController: UIViewController {

    var foods: [Food] = FoodUtils.getFoodList() // some expensive operations
    var fruits: [Fruit];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.fruits = FoodUtils.getFruitList() // some expensive operations
    }
}
```

I wonder for above class in iOS/Swift,

1. When `FoodUtils.getFoodList()` is prepared on runtime?
2. What is the good practice? preparing list inside viewDidLoad or in class scope? Which lifecycle of UIViewController will effect the memory on runtime for both cases?

Comment: `FoodUtils.getFruitList()` call some url or database request ?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski let it call some database operation.

Comment: Better practices is creating your list in `viewDidLoad` especially if it is a database operation

Comment: Why this is better practice can you please explain more?

Comment: I'm writing more explain answer, but @Pochi was faster. I think it's good answer

Comment: You can suggest if anything missing. It can be helpful too. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code (object initialization):

```
var foods: [Food] = FoodUtils.getFoodList() // some expensive operations
```

the expensive operations are performed when the view controller instance is created.

in the code (inside the viewDidLoad):

```
self.fruits = FoodUtils.getFruitList() // some expensive operations
```

the expensive operations are performed once the interface elements (IB outlets) have been hooked with the viewcontroller, and the views have been loaded.

In practice it doesn't make a difference because viewDidLoad is performed after the class has been initialized WHEN USING SEGUES (for programmatically shown VCs read the note at the end).

If you are talking about an operation that can take several seconds, then the best practice would be, to perform the expensive operations BEFORE showing the view controller while a busy view (a view with an activity indicator) is shown.

Alternatively, you could do it in the viewDidAppear method, and start the View controller with an activity indicator shown, then when the expensive operations finishes, hide the activity indicator and load your data.

As a matter of fact, the second approach is used very commonly, specially when showing big lists of data. You must have seen it when using apps that start with a spinning indicator until the data is ready to be displayed.

---

**Note:**

You can separate the timing of the 2 functions if you are showing your view controller programmatically, since the first one is performed when you use the "load from nib" method. While the second one is performed once you actually try to access any views inside it.

---

**Note 2:**

Expensive network operations should always be performed on background threads so that the UI is not blocked. Which is why people often show activity indicators while info is being retrieved in the background.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. It helps.